# using sed to rename files based on contents in OSX

Tags: sed

I'm using OSX, and I'm trying to take a piece of text within a .Rnw file, and then rename that file.

The file (text file) looks like this:

```
\begin{question}


A business incurs the following costs per unit: Labor  \$125/unit; Materials \$45/unit and rent  \$250,000/month. If the firm produces 1,000,000 units a month, the total variable costs equal
\begin{answerlist} 
\item \$125Million

\item \$45Million

\item \$1Million

\item \$170Million


\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{target}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0001}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

I want to grab the text in the \exname{} field, and make it the new title of the file. So, I want the file here to contain the contents as posted, and the whole file should be named "target.Rnw".

The link below got me started, but I can't make it work, such that the script takes the base file, then renames it based on that which is in the \exname{} field.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158447/grep-search-expression-and-rename-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```sh
$ cat ip.Rnw
\end{solution}

\exname{target}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0001}
\exshuffle{TRUE}

$ # use { or } as delimiters
$ # print second field if first field is \exname
$ awk -F'[{}]' '$1=="\\exname"{print $2}' ip.Rnw
target

$ # with sed, use capture group and backreference
$ sed -n 's/^\\exname{\(.*\)}/\1/p' ip.Rnw 
target

$ # echo is for testing purpose, remove it once things seem fine
$ echo mv ip.Rnw "$(awk -F'[{}]' '$1=="\\exname"{print $2 ".Rnw"}' ip.Rnw)"
mv ip.Rnw target.Rnw
```

Comment: This is excellent. Now, I just need to implement a loop of this. If I had many such files, ip.Rnw, ip2.Rnw, ip3.Rnw, ip4.Rnw,  . . . . ip300.Rnw in a single directory, I'd like to automate running this script through all of the files. Could you help me understand how to loop this such that all the files would be processed?