# using sed and awk to copy file name into a file

Tags: macos, awk, sed

I recently added a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811035/using-sed-to-rename-files-based-on-contents-in-osx/49811134#49811134) on how to use sed and awk to take a text string in a file and use it to name the file. Now I'm trying to figure out how to the the reverse - use the file name, and insert that text into the file at a specified point.

Using the same text example, say this file is called **test1.Rnw**:

```
\begin{question}


A business incurs the following costs per unit: Labor  \$125/unit; Materials \$45/unit and rent  \$250,000/month. If the firm produces 1,000,000 units a month, the total variable costs equal
\begin{answerlist} 
\item \$125Million

\item \$45Million

\item \$1Million

\item \$170Million


\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{target}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0001}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

I now want to take the file name `test1.Rnw` and insert that text within this file at the \exname{target} place, replacing the text `target`. Preferably, I could just insert `test1` and **not** the `.Rnw` extension here.

I was hoping I could use my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811035/using-sed-to-rename-files-based-on-contents-in-osx/49811134#49811134) (and the very nice response) to work out the solution, but I'm stuck.

=======

Comment: the result should be `\exname{test1}` right?

Comment: Allan, you are right that the resulting change should be that, from \exname{target} to \exname{test1}. The rest of the file (including the file name) should remain the same.

Comment: Could you check my 2 solutions (`sed`, `awk`) and let me know if it works for you? Thanks! Also note that in my examples the filename extension is `rnw` with a `r` in lowercase.

Comment: They do work, thanks so much for your help, Allan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different ways of doing the job, I would recommend to use `sed` since you want to replace some pattern in a file.

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat test1.rnw

\begin{question}


A business incurs the following costs per unit: Labor  \$125/unit; Materials \$45/unit and rent  \$250,000/month. If the firm produces 1,000,000 units a month, the total variable costs equal
\begin{answerlist} 
\item \$125Million

\item \$45Million

\item \$1Million

\item \$170Million


\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{target}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0001}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

**Command:**

```
FILENAME=`basename test1.rnw .rnw`; sed 's/^\\exname{target}/\\exname{'"$FILENAME"'}/' test1.rnw
```

**Explanations:**

- `basename` command is used with the filename and the extension to remove it from the filename, the result is stored in a variable called `FILENAME`.
- You use the `find and replace` feature of `sed` and replace `^\\exname{target}` (lines that start with `\exname{target}` by `\exname{` followed by the content of `FILENAME` variable and ending by `}`

**OUTPUT:**

```
\begin{question}


A business incurs the following costs per unit: Labor  \$125/unit; Materials \$45/unit and rent  \$250,000/month. If the firm produces 1,000,000 units a month, the total variable costs equal
\begin{answerlist} 
\item \$125Million

\item \$45Million

\item \$1Million

\item \$170Million


\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\item F. 
\end{answerlist}
\end{solution}

\exname{test1}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{0001}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

**TODO:**

- redirect the stdout to a file to save the result
- or use `-i` or `-i.bak` to do the changes in place (TAKE A BACKUP BEFORE)

**DOC:**

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

If you are a `awk` lover you can also use the following command to reach the same result:

```
awk '/^\\exname/{noext=FILENAME;sub(/\..*$/,"",noext);print "\\exname{"noext"}";next}1{print}' test1.rnw
```

**Explanations:**

- `1{print}` will print every line
- `/^\\exname/{noext=FILENAME;sub(/\..*$/,"",noext);print "\\exname{"noext"}";next}` for lines that start with `\exname` you access the FILENAME and remove the extension using `noext=FILENAME;sub(/\..*$/,"",noext)`, then you print the line using `print "\\exname{"noext"}"` and go to the `next` line to avoid double printing.

Comment: Thanks, Allan, I have tried these and it seems to work great. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to loop this over a bunch of files in a directory. I think that I can modify the code you have posted here, but the issue is that the file name seems hard coded into this. Is there a way to define it as a variable, such that I can loop this over a directory full of .Rnw files?

Comment: That sed script will fail when the file name contains backreference metacharacters such as `&` or `\<number>`. In the awk command `x{print "\\exname{"noext"}";next}1{print}` = `x{$0="\\exname{"noext"}"}1`

Answer (score 1):

Given `target` in `\exname{target}` is what you're interested in:

1) To name a file based on the value of `target`:

```
awk -F'[{}]' 'NR==FNR{if ($1=="\\exname") fname=$2; next} {print > fname}' file file
```

2) To replace `target` with the current file name:

```
awk -F'[{}]' '$1=="\\exname"{ $0 = $1 "{" FILENAME "}" } 1' file
```

You don't NEED a shell lop to operate on multiple files but it does have a simple, appealing consistent syntax in this case:

```
for file in *; do
   awk as above but replace `file` with `"$file"`
done
```

and if you want to replace the original file with the output of the awk command:

```
for file in *; do
   awk -F'[{}]' 'NR==FNR{if ($1=="\\exname") fname=$2; next} {print > fname}' "$file" "$file" &&
   rm -f "$file"
done

for file in *; do
   awk -F'[{}]' '$1=="\\exname"{ $0 = $1 "{" FILENAME "}" } 1' "$file" > tmp &&
   mv tmp "$file"
done
```

Comment: @exl what made you change your mind and de-select this as the accepted answer? It is after all the most robust, portable, flexible, and complete answer you got.